# How to create an html button with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

So I'm new to JavaScript and HTML. I know how to make an actual HTML button I just don't know how I could do it so that when something happens in an if statement it creates an HTML button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me see if I understod you correctly. You want to create a new HTML button using javascript?

Then something like this would work.

```html
<script>
  function createButton() {
    var myButton = document.createElement("BUTTON");
    var myText = document.createTextNode("Some text");
    myButton.appendChild(myText);
    document.body.appendChild(myButton);
  }
</script>

<body>
  <!-- Click the button to create a new button element -->
  <button onclick="createButton()">Create button</button>
</body>
```

Comment: Works great and was more explanatory than the others. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I re-read your post and saw you mentioned inside an if statement, so I made a simple example that just checks if there is any text inside the div you might want to put a button in and if there is text, add the button, if not, don't add the button.

```js
var content = document.getElementById('content'); // get the content div
var divs = content.getElementsByTagName('div'); // get all of the divs inside content div
var currentDiv; // to store a ref to the current div in the divs array

for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
    currentDiv = divs[i];
    // pretty contrived example but adds a button if there is already text
    // if there is no text just set the innerHTML to No Button
    if(currentDiv.textContent) { 
        var button = document.createElement('button');
        button.innerHTML = 'I\'m A Button!'; 
        currentDiv.appendChild(button);
    } else {
        currentDiv.innerHTML = 'No Button';
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
    <div class="foo"></div>
    <div class="bar">Something</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a div with an ID, then inside that if statement get the div like this:

```
document.getElementById("div-id").innerHTML = '`<button type="button">Click </button>`'
```

Note: Quotes must be how they are shown or javascript will throw an error